# A Compiled Function for the distance between a set of point

Tags: compile

I need to increase the speed of my code. I have a set of $n$ points in a square box of length $boxLength$.

```
n = 60;
boxLength = 20;
positions = Table[{Random[], Random[]}*boxLength, {i, 1, n}];
```

The module

```
RelativePosition[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{ri, rj, li, lj  , dr, Rij, sizeRij, untiRij},
   ri = positions[[i]];
   rj = positions [[j]];
   li = lmoment [[i]] ;
   lj = lmoment [[j]] ;

   dr = ri - rj;
   dr = dr - Round[dr/boxLength]*boxLength;
   Rij = dr + li - lj;  

   sizeRij = 1.*Norm[Rij];
   untiRij = Rij/sizeRij;

   Return [{sizeRij, untiRij }]
   ]
```

gives me the relative distance between two points. I used the following Compiled Function instead

```
RelativePosition2 = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},

  Module[{ii = i, jj = j, ri, rj, li, lj  , dr, Rij, sizeRij, untiRij},

   ri = positions[[ii]];
   rj = positions [[jj]];
   li = lmoment [[ii]] ;
   lj = lmoment [[jj]] ;

   dr = ri - rj;
   dr = dr - Round[dr/boxLength]*boxLength;
   Rij = dr + li - lj;  
   sizeRij = 1.*Norm[Rij];
   untiRij = Rij/sizeRij;

   Return [{sizeRij, untiRij }]
   ]
  ]

RelativePosition[1, 2]
```

It gives me a result but also tells me

```
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 31; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
```

What does the message mean? I cannot figure out what is wrong. Does it mean the Mathematica is not compiling the function?

Moreover, the compiled function is slower. The code

```
Do[RelativePosition[1, 2], {i, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives

```
{0.27862, Null}
```

white

```
Do[RelativePosition2[1, 2], {i, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives

```
{0.367405, Null}
```

Comment: `Norm` is a super general function so it does not compile. Use ``CompilePrint`` (read about it elsewhere here) to get a sense for what is preventing your function from truly compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Parallelize[DistanceMatrix[positions]]
```

For your example, `Timing` gives 0.002269 seconds, faster than your code.

If you want a list of the difference vectors:

```
Outer[Subtract, positions, positions, 1]
```

To get the normalized (unit-length) vector between each pair of points:

```
Map[Normalize, Outer[Subtract, positions, positions, 1], {2}]
```

Comment: This is great, but I need the unit vector between the points too.

Comment: Also, `DistanceMatrix` does not take into account the periodic boundary condition in my code.

Comment: Where in your problem do you state that the problem is periodic?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments and answers. `dr = dr - Round[dr/boxLength]*boxLength;` applies periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: I would simply create a new data set padding around boundaries.

Comment: `Outer[Plus, positions, -positions, 1]` faster than `Outer[Subtract, positions, 
  positions, 1]` :)

Comment: @mathe:  Interesting... I wonder why it is faster...

Answer (score 2):

Have look at `` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint@RelativePosition ``. Do you see the calls to `MainEvaluate`? They are due to the global variables `positions`, `lmoment`, and `boxLength` which are unknown to the compiled function. As a quick guess, I would suggest the following:

```
RelativePosition = Compile[{
   {positions, _Real, 2}, {lmoment, _Real, 2}, {boxLength, _Real},
   {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}
   },
  Module[{ii = i, jj = j, ri, rj, li, lj, dr, Rij, sizeRij, untiRij},
   ri = positions[[ii]];
   rj = positions[[jj]];
   li = lmoment[[ii]];
   lj = lmoment[[jj]];
   dr = ri - rj;
   dr = dr - Round[dr/boxLength]*boxLength;
   Rij = dr + li - lj;
   sizeRij = 1.*Norm[Rij];
   untiRij = Rij/sizeRij;
   Return[{sizeRij, untiRij}]]
  ]
```

However, the return value has a mixed type (it is not an array). That may cause trouble when you run it.

Comment: Thanks, I used your function and ran the code 

     RelativePosition[positions, lmoment, boxLength, 1, 2]

and it gave me:

CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument {0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3} at position 2 should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

{1.22977, {0.820146, -0.572154}}

Comment: Since you did not provide all relevant information, that's what had to happen: I had to make some assumptions about the nature of `positions`, `lmoment`, and `boxLength`. Apparently, some of them were wrong. But who is to blame for that?